# i want to make a loop that only runs through first colum in each row in a matrix

Tags: arrays, numpy

Lets say I have

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[40,50,60]])
```

and I want to make a loop that runs over the first column in each row with the condition that it must be under in range (1,30).
If not then the entire row must be extracted from the matrix.

I've so far came up with these codes and I feel like ...

```
n=-1
while n<=len(a):
  n=n+1
  for i in a[:,0]:
    if a[:,0] not in range(1,30):
        a=np.delete(a,(n),axis=0)
        
print(a)
```

and

```
n=-1
while n<len(a):
    n=n+1
    for row in range(len(a)):    
        for element in row:
            
            if element not in range(1,6):
                a=np.delete(a,(n),axis=0)
```

Comment: It is best to do just one `delete` for all `n`.  Don't do it repeatedly for 2 reasons - it is slow, and it's easy to mess up the count.  You may need to use the loop to identify the rows, but wait to do the delete.